# How to obtain private key of Elliptic curve by factorization?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

Okay i am trying to understand how the elliptic curve cryptography can be cracked by using factorization. Am not getting any clues after searching the internet can someone show me how your help will highly be appreciated

Comment: Yes one that's used cryptography

Comment: You cannot crack ECC with factorisation. Who gave you that idea? source?